# Does Talmud Torah truly trump literally every single other mitzvah?(or are there exceptions?)

Tags: torah-study

Talmud Torah is greater than all the other mitzvahs combined (Nefesh hachaim etc.  And many other  sources that say this), But how far does it go? Is one word of learning greater than keeping a full day of Shabbos? Or resisting yetzer hara for arayos ? Or is it just greater than ‘most’ mitzvos but not literally ‘all’..

Comment: No. "... Al havoda, Al hatorah, v'al gimilea chasadim" all 3 are needed to serve Hashem

Comment: Tzitzit is also valued as much as all the other Mitzvot

Comment: Even if Talmud Torah is literally k'neged kulam, the halacha still is that we are mevatel Torah to perform a mitzvah (generally speaking). So the word "trump" might not be the best word in this context.

Comment: The way I see it: the various statements in Chazal, each deeming different things "which outweighs the rest of the Torah" is like saying "gas is the car's most important element", "the steering wheel is the most important", "the tires are the most important" etc. They're all integral parts which the car cannot operate without. So too these *mamare* Chazal are just to emphasize each one's importance. The Torah is the most important for the simple reason that without it one can't know God's will and live like a Jew.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Joeg. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 5):

The opinion of [R. Joseph B. Soloveitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik) is quoted by R. David Holzer:

**The Rav Thinking Aloud p. 70**

> *[DH:] What do we mean by תלמוד תורה כנגד כולם?*
>
> It is not that this *mitzvah* is equal to all the *mitzvos*, but rather
>   that it brings the person to do all the other *mitzvos*. The whole
>   purpose of the *limud* is that it comes to *asiah*, and *asiah* is the
>   *ikkur*.

Comment: The [Rambam](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%90#%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90) explains the *Mishnah* like this.

Comment: Which volume of *Thinking Aloud* is this from?

Comment: @DonielF The first one (genral discussions, not on the parshah).